# Why is ObjectOutputStream.writeObject faster than write bytes when writing a byte array?

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I did a small benchmark test and found that `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` is faster than `ObjectOutputStream.write(byte[] bytes)` but I can't seem to find a possible explanation as under the hood, `writeObject` will call `ObjectOutputStream.write(byte[] bytes)` indirectly

***Test code***

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) (i % 256);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try(ObjectOutputStream ostream2 = new ObjectOutputStream(out2)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            ostream2.writeInt(bytes.length);
            ostream2.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }

        out2.reset();

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            ostream2.writeInt(bytes.length);
            ostream2.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("write byte[] took: " + ((end - start) / 1000) + " micros");
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try(ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            ostream.writeObject(bytes);
        }

        out.reset();

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            ostream.writeObject(bytes);
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("writeObject took: " + ((end - start) / 1000) + " micros");
    }
}
```

***Output***

> write byte[] took: 15445 micros
>
> writeObject took: 3111 micros

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` conserves written objects. If you've already written that object, it only writes a handle to the same object, not the entire object.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. I replaced the code to have a new array everytime and the write byte array is now faster than writeObject. I totally forgot about the caching done by writeObject

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a slight modification of your code:

```
public class Test {

  public static final int REPS = 10000;

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ObjectOutputStream ostream2 = new ObjectOutputStream(out2)) {
      writeBytes(ostream2);
      out2.reset();
      long start = System.nanoTime();
      writeBytes(ostream2);
      long end = System.nanoTime();
      System.out.println("write byte[] took: " + ((end - start) / 1000) + " micros");
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
      writeObject(ostream);
      out.reset();
      long start = System.nanoTime();
      writeObject(ostream);
      long end = System.nanoTime();
      System.out.println("writeObject took: " + ((end - start) / 1000) + " micros");
    }
  }

  private static void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream ostream) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
      final byte[] bytes = bytes();
      ostream.writeObject(bytes);
    }
  }

  private static void writeBytes(ObjectOutputStream ostream2) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
      final byte[] bytes = bytes();
      ostream2.writeInt(bytes.length);
      ostream2.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
  }

  static byte[] bytes() {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[REPS];
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
      bytes[i] = (byte) i;
    }
    return bytes;
  }
}
```

Now the result is

```
write byte[] took: 51697 micros
writeObject took: 57203 micros
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I totally forgot about the caching mechanism in writeObject